# Normal simple subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

> Suppose that $S \lhd G$ is a non-abelian simple normal subgroup of $G$. Further, suppose that every automorphism given by the action by conjugation of $G$ on $S$ is an inner automorphism of $S$. Then $G= S \times C_G(S)$.

As an exercise I am supposed to prove or find a counterexample to this assertion. I think that it is true. My proof is as follows: since $S$ is normal, then $C_G(S)$ is also normal.

For $g \in G$ the automorphism $\tau_g$ given by conjugation is always an inner automorphism of $S$ when restricted to $S$, so its coset in ${\rm Out}(S)$ is trivial. In particular, since ${\rm Inn}(S) = S$ because $S$ is simple, there exists $s \in S$ such that $\tau_{gs} = {\rm Id_S}$. Hence, $G=SC_G(S)$.

Since $S$ is simple, $Z(S) =1$ so in particular $S \cap C_G(S) = 1$.

Then $G$ is a direct product of $S$ and $C_G(S)$, and we are done.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand what the action of $G/S$ on $S$ is supposed to be: presumably we start with the conjugation action of $G$ on $S$ (well-defined because $S$ is normal), then we're supposed to notice that each element of $S$ acts trivially on $S$, so this descends to an action of $G/S$ on $S$. However, I don't understand why it should be the case "each element of $S$ acts trivially on $S$" — in particular this would imply that $S$ is abelian, which doesn't seem to be one of the assumptions. Am I missing something?

Comment: as diracdeltafunk said, for $G/N$ to act on $N$ by conjugation in a natural well-defined way, $N$ needs to be abelian. (This is easy to check.) Therefore, the hypothesis isn't even well-defined and it doesn't make sense to even attempt a proof. (On top of that, in your proof, you conclude that, since $S$ is simple, $Z(S)=1$, but now you are assuming that $S$ is non-abelian!)

Comment: On the other hand, in the case when the statement is indeed well-defined (that is, when $S$ is abelian), then there are plenty of counterexamples. (For example, if $G$ is abelian, and $S$ is a simple subgroup.)

Comment: I had rephrased the original question in a wrong way, and omitted the fact that $S$ is non-abelian. Thank you both for making me notice that! Does the question make sense now?

Comment: The question now makes sense! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me! You should make sure to mention in your proof that $S$ is non-abelian as well as simple (otherwise you can't conclude $S \cong \operatorname{Inn}(S)$ or $Z(S) = 1$). It also might be good to modify your explanation a bit when you conclude that $G = S C_G(S)$ – the intermediate step is that $\tau_{gs} = \operatorname{id}_S \implies gs \in C_G(S)$, from which you can conclude that $g \in C_G(S)S$. Of course $C_G(S) S = S C_G(S)$ but that's an *additional* intermediate step which you didn't write down. It'd be a good idea to expand this explanation so all of these small steps are included (and/or modify the argument to begin with $\tau_{sg} = \operatorname{id}_S$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!